# Getting to Sabiha Gokcen (SAW) airport early in the morning across Bosphorus

Tags: airport-transfer, turkey, istanbul, saw

My flight departs at 8:30 from Sabiha Gokcen airport in Istanbul. Can there be any problems getting there in time from a hotel in Fatih? When should I depart from the hotel to get there in time for sure? What is the best and/or cheapest means of transportation at this time? Is Bosphorus closed at night?

Comment: Unfortunately IMHO your answer is much too specific for yourself. In Travel.SE only questions should be asked which are of value for people reading it afterwards and I doubt that many people want to find out how they can get from a hotel in Fatih to the Instanbul airport at specifically 8:30.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too specific to be useful to anybody but the asker.